# Including files in assembly 80x86

Tags: file, assembly

I am just learning assembly and I made a simple procedure. But how would I put that procedure in a separate file, and how would I include it in the main.asm?

```
simple proc 
    .
    .
    .
simple ENDP
```

Lets say thats the procedure I want to include into the main. What filetype would I make, .asm or .h?

Also how would I call that function in my main.asm?

Comment: What Assembler?  Each one is different.  You can make the file type anything you want, has no meaning.  Your code needs to be in the code section though, then you just include it in your main.asm file.

Comment: X86 include files have a suffix of .inc, but these are meant to be used for defintions, equates, ... , not for code. You can have an assembler project that consists of multiple .asm files for the code. For a project that includes asm and C code, there's a utility called h2inc that converts a C .h file into an assembler .inc file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified which assembler you're using, but here's how you could do it using MASM32:

Declare prototypes for your external procedures in a `.inc` file; let's call it **external.inc**:

```
; Declare a procedure prototype that takes two DWORD arguments

external_adder PROTO :DWORD, :DWORD
```

---

Then define the bodies of these procedures in a corresponding `.asm` file; let's call it **external.asm**:

```
.686p
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

.code

; Define the body of external_adder

external_adder PROC arg1:DWORD, arg2:DWORD
    mov eax,arg1
    add eax,arg2
    ret
external_adder ENDP

END
```

---

Whenever you want to use one of these procedures from another `.asm` file you include the `.inc` file. Let's create another file called **main.asm**:

```
.686p
.model flat,stdcall 
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc    ; for ExitProcess
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc      ; for crt_printf
include external.inc                    ; for external_adder

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data

format db "123 + 456 = %d",13,10,0

.code

start:

invoke external_adder,123,456

; Print the result, then close down the program
invoke crt_printf, ADDR format, eax
invoke ExitProcess,0

END start
```

---

To build this you would do:

```
ml /c /coff main.asm
ml /c /coff external.asm
link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE main.obj external.obj
```